# How to remove or replace brackets in a string?

Tags: excel, perl, replace, spreadsheet, substitution

```
my $book = Spreadsheet::Read->new();
my $book = ReadData 
('D:\Profiles\jmahroof\Desktop\Scheduled_Build_Overview.xls');
my $cell = "CD7";
my $n = "1";
my $send = $book->[$n]{$cell};
```

The above code gets data from a spreadsheet, then prints the content of a cell that I know has text in. It has text of exactly the following format: text(text)

I need to replace the open bracket with a empty space and I need to remove the close bracket. I have tried the below code to substitute the open bracket for an empty space however it does not seem to work.

```
$send =~ s/(/ /g;
print $send;
```

Comment: Try to escape the meta character `(` : `$send =~ s/\(/ /g`

Comment: Solved, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bracket is seen as part of the code, just escape it.

```
$send =~ s/\(/ /;
print $send;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only replace one char with another, you don't want a substitution, but a *transliteration*. That's the [`tr///` function in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html). Since the pattern is just a list of chars, and not an actual regex, you don't need to escape the open parenthesis `(`. There is also no `/g` flag. It just substitutes all occurrences.

```
$send =~ tr/(/ /;
```

The main difference to a regular expression substitution is that the transliterations get compiled at *compile time*, not at *run time*. That makes the `tr///` faster than a `s///`, especially in a loop.

See the [full documentation in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2F_SEARCHLIST_%2F_REPLACEMENTLIST_%2Fcdsr).

Comment: That's really interesting that they get compiled at a compile time, I will definitely consider using this. ;)

Comment: @JamalMahroof that makes it harder to use it with dynamic patterns. It's a pain. But this usecase is exactly what it's for.